# How to get to know the XML file and its path for that template Path Hint in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, xml, paths

As we can enable template path hints in settings along with blocks but there is no option to show from which xml file it is coming in the frontend. How should I know which xml file to write to move, remove and add template to that location. Sometimes it become very difficult to find the file related to that template path because there are so much files presented in the folder.

Comment: You can search by the `phtml` path in your project, in your ide, ssh, local project

Comment: When i do that sometimes there are too much files then it create a mess to found the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I download a copy of the site, then search for tags within the code (often "class" html tags)  You can usually quickly work back from there to find the CSS, .phtml and .xml

I use fileseek as it is free to do this

Comment: There are too much files how to choose the right one. Sometimes on phtml file is added in to number of xml files. How to choose the right one to save time.